# Как парсить "Google+", чтобы получить сегментированную базу?

Tags: javascript, google-api, парсер, gmail

Можно ли с помощью парсера достать из Google+: Email, Имя, Фамилию, Возраст, Место работы, Место проживания, Семья (имя и email), Подписки.

Если вы считаете, что нельзя, напишите, пожалуйста, почему.

Comment: Может лучше использовать [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/?hl=ru)?  
А вот на счёт email, я сильно сомневаюсь.